# Winforms app wont run on production server

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, clickonce

I would really appreciate any help as to why i get a ***system.io.filenotfoundexception*** message when i double click the **setup.exe** on the production server's desktop after installing the app from a CD. I had earlier deployed the winforms app using VS2010 ClickOnce tool, on the Development server (WinVista) to a CD, then ran the CD on the prod server and installed the app to the prod server.
What could be the missing required file(s), or were the files installed in the wrong location/directory??
Or have i missed out something/done the wrong thing while setting the configs in ClickOnce?

Comment: Is it possible for you to retrieve and post the stacktrace/inner-exception(s) of your filenotfoundexception?

Comment: Maybe not all files are deployed? Just compare your local dir and installation dir on deployment server.

Answer (score 0):

What is the installation URL that was used when the C/O application was published? Did you check the box that says you are deploying to a CD?

Do you have an update URL or an installation URL that the application can use to get updates, or are you only providing changes via CD?

If you are not going to provide updates via a file share or web server, I would have the deployment NOT include a deployment provider URL in the deployment (there's a checkbox in the publishing options). Then it will set it to the CD drive when it installs, and look there for updates when the user runs it.

Answer (score 0):

- is the setup.exe executed as administrator ?
- check how resources are used, f.e images in resouces - do they have "embedded Resource/linked at compiletime" or "copy to outup" activated ?